# Has Microsoft released a patch for MS17-010?

Tags: windows, exploit, patching

Is there a patch or fix to safeguard against the MS17-010 (EternalSynergy + EternalRomance + EternalChampion) exploit yet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it was patched. [This page](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4013389/title) lists all the patches for MS17-010 across the different Windows operating systems and versions.

You can also disable SMBv1 for improved security, by following the steps [listed in this knowledgebase article](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/security-updates/securitybulletins/2017/ms17-010#windows-smb-information-disclosure-vulnerability--cve-2017-0147--):

> For desktop operating systems:
>
> - Open Control Panel, click Programs, and then click Turn Windows features on or off.
> - In the Windows Features window, clear the SMB1.0/CIFS File Sharing Support checkbox, and then click OK to close the window.
> - Restart the system.
>
> For server operating systems:
>
> - Open Server Manager and then click the Manage menu and select Remove Roles and Features.
> - In the Features window, clear the SMB1.0/CIFS File Sharing Support check box, and then click OK to close the window.
> - Restart the system.